# Maths And Technology: calculating angles of mirrors for a laser.

Tags: geometry, physics

HELP// maths and technology(light)
hello! So, I have a class project in which we have to secure a piece of art in a 'museum'. In this project we have to use a laser, 2 mirrors and a sensor (basic things). They have given us coordinates of the places where these will go: LASER(0,0) MIRROR1(5,60) MIRROR2(110,40) and SENSOR(90,15). This is on a normal coordinate system. Now, we have to calculate the angles on which our mirrors will stand. we also have to calculate the angle of the laser. our laser will then have to reach the sensor passing through the lasers. For info: i am in 9th grade so the mathematics level isn't very high. we've learned the PYTHAGORAS THEORY, sin cos tan and functions y=ax+b... and much more

thank you if you help me, i will greatly appreciatie it.

Comment: Have you tried drawing the information on a sheet of graph paper?  With any luck the problem you were given will turn out to involve some pretty standard right triangles.

Comment: Yes, i have tried this, and unfortunately, it turns out to be a random 4-sider.

Comment: The path of the light beam is three straight line segments, and what I'm getting at is that each segment is the hypotenuse of a right triangle.  So with right triangles, it seems in your list of topics (Pythagorean formula, trigonometric functions) to be able to express these angles.  Keep in mind that light bounces off of the mirrors with an incidence angle equal for the incoming and outgoing beams.

Comment: the angles are not always 90°... so i think we have to look for a right angle triangle in the shape. i need the angles of the incidence and reflection...

Comment: actually the angles are never 90°...

Comment: The coordinate axes are at right angles, so each segment of the light path is indeed the hypotenuse of a right triangle with legs parallel to the coordinate axes.  Draw it on graph paper and it should become clear.

Comment: i have tried, and because of the random points on the axes, when i join them becomes a totally random 4sided shape, it is not a rectangle or a square or even a trapezium... just 3 connected sides

Comment: i THINK i have found the solution, but still i really appreciate your help. THANK YOU AGAIN !!

Answer (score 1):

The law of relection is ... incident and reflected angles are equal.

Join the points by straight lines which are the incident and reflected rays. Draw their bisectors which are normal to the mirrors. Draw short perpendiculars to each of four  normals which now represent the mirrors.

Comment: but that doesn't really make a difference, does it? maybe im not understanding it well...

Comment: Make the drawing, all will become clear soon

Comment: yes! now is see. 2 right angle triangles are formed, and then by using the equations for the distance in axes, i can find my angles! i will ask this to my group and teacher tomorrow. thank you so much

Comment: I suggested a geometric construction which you can try independently,